# VS 2019 C++ Missing symbols in pch.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've seen the related question regarding `"_T()" not found`. I have a console app. The "Debug" version of the console app compiles and runs fine. When I try to compile it as a "Release" version I first get hundreds of `_T() Not Found`. I tried adding `#include <tchar.h>` to `pch.h` which was completely ineffective. Based on what I found in the question about undefined `_T()` I read, I added the text

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define _T(x)      L ## x
#else /* _UNICODE */
#define _T(x)      x
#endif /* _UNICODE */

#include <tchar.h>
#include "framework.h"
```

to pch.h before `#include "framework.h"`. The compiler noticed but now complained  as follows:

```
Error   C2039   '_tcscpy_s': is not a member of '`global namespace''    Anon    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\atlmfc\include\atlchecked.h 111
```

plus a few hundred other similar messages.

This is not the first time this has happened. Every project I've tried to build with VS2019 eventually has this happen to it. And, this happens compiling a completely pristine "pch.h" that I had not (initially) modified at all before this error occurred.

I've already tried deleting VS and reinstalling it. My OS is Windows 10 (64-bit)

The list of **Include** directories is the same for both the **Debug** and **Release** configurations.

I feel that this must be related to something in the way Visual Studio is configured, but mostly I need help fixing it. The compiler seems to be getting tangled up in its own header files. What can I do to analyze/fix this?

**ADDENDUM**:
Just since I started writing this question I have gone back to my project and tried the Debug version again. Now it is getting the same errors. And I made no changes since the previous time I built it earlier today.

Comment: What version of VS2019 are you using ? I'm on 16.9.0 now ,but one of the previous versions of 16.8 had some strange behaviours. When I changed a header file a normal build was generating ridiculous errors (sometimes even when doing a clear first) ,while a re-build did not.

Comment: The behavior is consistent with different `.cpp` files having different `#include` sequences before the precompiled header. Make sure `pch.h` is the *first* header included in all files that use or generate it.

Comment: @engf-010 I don't know. I update frequently; it should be the latest. I didn't find any info in the compiler itself that would tell me.

Comment: @dxiv All this crap came from simply compiling a pristine copy of pch.cpp.

Comment: menu:Help\About ... or Visual Studio Installer

Comment: @Logicrat Can't duplicate it with a pristine project, and never saw it happen with a pristine project. If you get the errors on a new unmodified project then there is something wrong with your VS installation. If you only get the errors after modifications, then please edit the question and post those modifications (assuming you are the OP, that is).

Comment: @dxiv I'm trying to help but I got nothing.

Comment: This has happened on a pristine project. I'm more convinced than ever that there is an installation problem. I have VS2013 and VS2017 on the same machine; maybe I should uninstall them.

Comment: In this case, I did get the Debug version of my project built and running properly. The error messages started when I first tried to build the Release version.

Comment: I suggest you could make a small program to determine whether it is a problem with the compiler VS or a problem with tchar.h.